# Disabling Ribbon button after clicking in MS CRM 2011?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Want to disable the ribbon button in MS CRM 2011, after clicking once it should be disabled

Answer (score 3):

The button could set a boolean field on click, unless there is already something on the record that the button has changed.
An enable rule for the button could include the boolean field or whatever changed on the record.

Ribbon Workbench is a great tool for adding a display rule: http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx

Gareth Tucker has a great post on the topic here:
http://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/11/25/dynamically-disable-ribbon-buttons-in-dynamics-crm/